# How can I enter query-replace in GNU Emacs using a repeatable function based on values in the line currently at point

Tags: emacs

I'd like to take the following data and query-replace occurences of each word identifier with the corresponding numeric identifier using some sort of repeatable function.

```
-1 ACT/CNS
-2 AG NFC
-3 AID
-4 BBG
-5 BIA
-6 BLM
-7 BOC
-8 BPD
-9 CCC
-10 CDC
-11 Census
```

In other words, with point at

```
-1 ACT/CNS
^
```

I'd like to be able to hit a key and launch into the following command

```
query-replace RET ACT/CNS RET -1 RET
```

I tried defining a keyboard macro but there seems to be enough jumping between buffers and M-x calls to confuse the kbmacro and make it unusable.

Thoughts?

Comment: Where did you want to do the replacement?  In that same buffer, or a different one?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to create the keyboard macro which did replacement of the symbols with the numbers.

```
C-a                     ;; move-beginning-of-line
M-f                     ;; forward-word
C-f                     ;; forward-char
C-SPC                   ;; set-mark-command
C-e                     ;; move-end-of-line
M-w                     ;; kill-ring-save
C-a                     ;; move-beginning-of-line
C-SPC                   ;; set-mark-command
M-f                     ;; forward-word
M-w                     ;; kill-ring-save
M-%                     ;; query-replace
C-y                     ;; yank
M-y                     ;; yank-pop
RET                     ;; newline-and-indent
C-y                     ;; yank
M-y                     ;; yank-pop
RET                     ;; newline-and-indent
```

When the cursor is on the line for "-1 ACT/CNS", the above will start the query/replace with the values you want - in the current buffer.

Unless you're doing this a lot (as in, more than just today), I'd stick with the macro because it's easy to set up.